# Some specific WFS service result is not as per bbox

Tags: geoserver

I am using `OSM` tiles to rendered map and using leaflet to render it. I have few `WFS` service configured to show data. Request to WFS service are generated based on map canvas area by selecting bbox through:

```
map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
```

My WFS request URL is [generated dynamically](http://gisservices.zwolle.nl/arcgis/services/Adres_en_gebouw/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=text/xml;%20subType=gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsf/1.0.0/0&version=1.1.0&typeName=Adres_en_gebouw:Ligplaats&bbox=52.5138899878197,6.097787618637085,52.51687048383939,6.10465407371521,EPSG:4326&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:28992&)

Our default projection is `EPSG:4326` while WFS has `rn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:28992`. This is taken out from GetCapabilities. When we render result of WFS on map then layers are rendered on map properly but result returned by WFS is not matching bbox of map. It shifted as per mentioned in image.[Map and WFS result layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxrBO.jpg)

```
Note: Output of WFS is text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsf/1.0.0/0
```

Comment: you need to reproject the WFS features to match the map projection. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/change-vector-projection-in-openlayers

Comment: Problem resolved:I am using leaflet and there is no projection definition added for 28992. So when WFS data rendered which has projection 28992. For the first time load WFS data projects accurately because I have added projection definition for 28992 on map. When I do map panning and new WFS data fetched based on bounding box, then projection got disturbed.  I have created new object of L.Proj.CRS('28992',definitionadded here) while rendering WFS data so now it is working perfectly. Thanks @iant. Your suggestion worked for me